# django fetching wrong datetime from database (inconsistent time on DateTimeField)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

[image]
In the admin panel showing my correct date and time, but when I'm fetching that data there is getting the wrong time, but the date is correct.

Please see this screenshot you will get my problem.

Comment: Might be due to the timezone you are using.

Comment: can you share the code block that you save the dates?

Comment: @SırrıKırımlıoğlu

updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

Comment: any solutions? @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/). It explains why this happens. When displaying from the database just use this:

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime

updated_at = localtime(otp_obj.updated_at)
```

Comment: If I Use 

```
USE_TZ = False
```

its works. what is the difference between these two?

Comment: It is for disabling or enabling DateTime support. When it is enabled, you should save your datatimes with timezone. I am not sure ''auto_now_add'' or ''auto_now'' use which time function, but when you change the setting to ''USE_TZ = True'' do not use them.